# Limiting the TaxonomyWebTaggingControl possible selections

Tags: web-part, taxonomy

Assuming I have a term set with all the countries.
The first level is the continents
The second level is the countries.
No I am building a web part with a dropdown of the continents and a WebTaggingControl from the term set.
How can I force the WebTaggingControl to show only the continent selected in the dropdown?

The actual usage is not with countries but this is a good representation of the issue :-)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It could be accomplished by specifying [AnchorId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.anchorid.aspx) property for [TaxonomyWebTaggingControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomywebtaggingcontrol.aspx) control.
This property allows to specify *ID of parent Term for any valid value in control*.

---

Assume we have the following structure for the countries:

- the first level is the continents
- the second level is the countries

[image]

If we initialize TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control and specify for AnchorId  *Europe* Term Id value

```
 /// <summary>
/// Initializing TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control
/// </summary>
/// <param name="countryControl"> </param>
/// <param name="session"></param>
/// <param name="continentTerm"></param>
private void InitCountriesControl(TaxonomyWebTaggingControl countryControl, TaxonomySession session, Term continentTerm)
{
    countryControl.SSPList = continentTerm.TermStore.Id.ToString();
    countryControl.AnchorId = continentTerm.Id;
    countryControl.TermSetList = continentTerm.TermSet.Id.ToString();
}
```

then only **countries for selected continent will be displayed**

[image]

For more details and how to implement Country picker based on Countries term set please see my blog - [Using SharePoint TaxonomyWebTaggingControl control: specifying parent terms](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/using-sharepoint-taxonomywebtaggingcontrol-control-specifying-parent-terms/)